# Angular 2 component does not work with *ngIf

Tags: angular

I have an error message component to show one error message at a time that does not work with *ngIf, so I have to manipulate it's visibility with ngClass and I don't quite understand why.

```
<input type="text" id="email" class="form-group__input"
    pAutofocus
    required
    email
    name="email"
    [(ngModel)]="model.email"
    #email="ngModel"
>
```

Instead of doing:

```
<p-errors [control]="email" *ngIf="email.touched">
    <p-error name="required">Please enter your email.</p-error>
    <p-error name="email">Please make sure that your email is a valid one.</p-error>
</p-errors>
```

I have to do:

```
<p-errors [control]="email" [ngClass]="{'display--none': email.untouched}">
    <p-error name="required">Please enter your email.</p-error>
    <p-error name="email">Please make sure that your email is a valid one.</p-error>
</p-errors>
```

Without *ngIf the structure looks like this: One of the error messages have true and the other null:

[image]

But with *ngIf the errors are both null even if *ngIf is true:

[image]

p-error.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'p-error',
    template: `
        <div class="form-group__error-message"
            *ngIf="show"
        >
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    `
})
export class PErrorComponent {
    @Input() name: string;
    show: boolean = false;
}
```

p-errors.component.ts

```
import {
    Component, Input,
    QueryList, ContentChildren, AfterContentInit, OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { PErrorComponent } from './p-error.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'p-errors',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class PErrorsComponent implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() control: FormControl;
    @ContentChildren(PErrorComponent) contentChildren: QueryList<PErrorComponent>;

    private statusChangesSubscription: Subscription;

    updateErrors(status: string) {
        let showError: string;
        const errors: string[] = status === 'INVALID' ? Object.keys(this.control.errors) : [];
        loop: for (const error of errors) {
            if (this.control.hasError(error)) {
                showError = error;
                break loop;
            }
        }
        this.contentChildren.forEach((pErrorComponent: PErrorComponent) => {
            pErrorComponent.show = pErrorComponent.name === showError ? true : false;
        });
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.updateErrors(this.control.status);
        this.statusChangesSubscription = this.control.statusChanges.subscribe((status: string) => {
            this.updateErrors(status);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.statusChangesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

It would be awesome if I could understand why this is happening. I feel like I have to understand this before I can go on.

Comment: Do you have defined email in p-errors component?

Comment: No I have not defined email in p-errors component.

Comment: I think, the problem is in `@ContentChildren(PErrorComponent)`. ngIf removes elements from DOM and `contentChildren` becomes emtpy